# ng-grid does not take 100% width on page load but shows fine on resize

Tags: angularjs

The ng-grid with angular js does not take 100% width on page load. Here is my code:

```
    <tabs ng-cloak>
        <pane title="Test Plan">
            <tabs>
                <pane title="Include Tests">
                    <div ng-controller="includedTestPlanGridCntrl">
                        <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
                    </div>
                </pane>
                <pane title="Excluded Tests">
                    <div ng-controller="excludedTestPlanGridCntrl">
                        <div class="gridStyle1" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
                    </div>
                </pane>
            </tabs>
        </pane>
        <pane title="Advanced Planning">
            Some text here
        </pane>
    </tabs>
```

The grid appears correctly if I resize.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have worked out a solution for this.

Just add the following lines in  the ng-grid.js inside the ng.EventProvider.

```
setInterval(function() {
    domUtilityService.RebuildGrid($scope,grid);
}, 30);
```

Comment: While this fixes the problem, it rebuilds the grid every 30 ms which creates a great deal of performance issues.

Comment: Yes it does creates a performance issue.. but it was the only thing that worked

Comment: Can someone show an example of how to inject the "domUtilityService". I've gone around the Horn of Africa trying to figure out why it's constantly erroring as being undefined... Much appreciated to atone who can help.

Comment: This is old, but in case other people have this i'll put it. This is in my controller.         $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
            $timeout(function() {
                if($scope.grid.$gridServices)
                    $scope.grid.$gridServices.DomUtilityService.RebuildGrid($scope.grid.$gridScope, $scope.grid.ngGrid);
            }, 100);
        });

Comment: You dont need to inject the DomUtility. Just use it after your gridConfig has already been initialized. $scope.grid is my object with columnDefs etc.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem using the tabs from [Angular UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

The simplest fix is to trigger the `resize` event on a parent element of ng-grid,
preferably when the tab containing ng-grid is selected.

The ng-grid will resize itself correctly this event is triggered.

Use something like this:

```
function onTabSelect() {
  $('.grid-container').trigger('resize');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'gridData',
        init:function(grid,$scope) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $scope.gridOptions.$gridServices.DomUtilityService.RebuildGrid(
                    $scope.gridOptions.$gridScope,
                    $scope.gridOptions.ngGrid
                );
            },1000);
        }
    };
```

Replace "gridOptions" with variable you use and bingo!

Answer (score 5):

Try setting ng-if to only include the grid when there is data to show:  (ng-hide did not work for me)

```
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions" ng-if="myViewModel.Data.length"></div>
```

Source:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/855

Related question: [When ng-grid change visibility from invisible to visible by ng-hide, grid width not being re-calculated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19804733/when-ng-grid-change-visibility-from-invisible-to-visible-by-ng-hide-grid-width)

Comment: This is the only option that appears to work for me. Unfortunately, where I was only getting 11 rows before, now I get the full 1000 and ng-grid screeches to a grinding halt. Grrr...

Answer (score 2):

You could use the grids ngGridLayoutPlugin [(found here)](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/plugins/ng-grid-layout.js) and call it in the controllers init function.

```
    var layoutPlugin = new ngGridLayoutPlugin();


    $scope.init = function() {
        $scope.gridOptions = {
            plugins: [layoutPlugin],
        };


        window.setTimeout(function(){
            layoutPlugin.updateGridLayout();
        }, 100);

    };
```

Answer (score 1):

In case if you have handler after grid is loaded, then you can call a method which actually re-renders the grid when window is resized.

```
gridApi.core.handleWindowResize()
```

This might help you whenever you want to call resize event manually.

Answer (score 0):

This change would be much better in terms of CPU load.

Line 2904

https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/a0d693e413e993145bff274375f1102770585e59/ng-grid-2.0.6.debug.js

From this:

```
    // we have to set this to false in case we want to autogenerate columns with no initial data.
    grid.lateBoundColumns = false;
    $scope.columns = [];
    grid.config.columnDefs = a;
    grid.buildColumns();
    grid.configureColumnWidths();
    grid.eventProvider.assignEvents();
    domUtilityService.RebuildGrid($scope, grid);
}, true);
```

To this:

```
    // we have to set this to false in case we want to autogenerate columns with no initial data.
    grid.lateBoundColumns = false;
    $scope.columns = [];
    grid.config.columnDefs = a;
    grid.buildColumns();
    grid.configureColumnWidths();
    grid.eventProvider.assignEvents();
    setTimeout(function() {domUtilityService.RebuildGrid($scope,grid);}, 1);
}, true);
```

Comment: Having the same problem in 2.0.7.  Your proposed solution did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I moved ng-grid library scripts after all scripts, that changed DOM tree.
In other words:
with problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ng-grid-2.0.7.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mmenu.min.all.js"></script>
```

fix the problem:

```
<script src="jquery.mmenu.min.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ng-grid-2.0.7.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This does not fix the problem in my case

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will save someone else the time I spent on a work around in scenarios where this is still a problem.  For me, my last column width was "*", and cutoff is not an issue, so using a wrapper div works.  I was also not interested in a javascript timeout solution.

HTML:

```
<div class="gridWidthWrapper">
    <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'dataList',
    columnDefs: [{field: 'type', displayName: 'Type', width: 120},
      {field: 'description', displayName: 'Description', width: '*'}]
  };
```

CSS:

```
.gridWidthWrapper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.gridStyle {
/* width: 100%;  --- 100% not sizing on load - using gridWidthWrapper class to obtain 100% */
  width: 2000px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are all complicated, it is not the best way to made changes into source code..

Just add to the div

```
data-ng-show="myData.length"
```

Where myData is the Grid data source, ensure data load async or set $timeout on the load data method.

I know ngGrid has a method called `getPagedDataAsync`, call it from JQuery document ready, some like this:

```
$(function(){
   getPagedDataAsync(...)
});
```

if you are not paging data, just call your custom data load method from JQuery document ready.

Hope it helps :)

Regards