# When ng-grid change visibility from invisible to visible by ng-hide, grid width not being re-calculated

Tags: angularjs

I have a ng-grid with ng-hide attribute and width:100% style.

```
<div class="grid-style" data-ng-grid="gridOpt"
  style="display: inline-block; height: 300px; width: 100%;">
</div>
```

This grid is invisible at first time, and become visible after I select some option in my HTML form.
When this grid become visible, it's width is wrong.

Are there any approach to force update Grid's layout ?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Maybe it is related to [this issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/469). I created a new directive as a workaround:

```
myDirectives.directive('resizeWhen', function () {
    'use strict';
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            var resizeExpr = attrs.resizeWhen,
            listener = scope.$watch(resizeExpr, function (value) {
                if (value) {
                    elem.resize(); 
                    listener();
                }
            }, false);
        }
    };
});
```

You can use this like the following:

```
<div id="searchResultsGrid" ng-grid="searchResultsGrid" 
     resize-when="mode == 'search'">
</div>
```

Note, that you need jQuery for the above directive to work.

Comment: I had the same issue and forcing resize using a directive works. But in my case I watched the element's :visible property.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting ng-if to only include the grid when there is data to show:

```
<div class="grid-style" data-ng-grid="gridOpt" data-ng-if="myViewModel.Data.length"
  style="display: inline-block; height: 300px; width: 100%;">
</div>
```

Source:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/855